# Image file size to area ratio

Tags: image, image-compression, image-size

I'm writing a tool to detect images on our website that should be flagged for manual intervention to reduce file size. If a "large" image is 100K that might be fine, but if a "small" image is 100K, someone forgot to flatten it or compress it.

I'm looking at the "file density" of an image as the ratio filesize/(height x width). Is there a term for this? Is there some guidance about what a reasonable range for this density should be, so that I can flag images? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: This sounds way too simplified (ignoring image-type: natural vs. non-natural; colors). The only thing which is slightly related i know of is [bits per pixel](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_one_relate_compression_ratio_CR_with_bits_per_pixel_bpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the file size is given in bits, then that fraction is known as the bitrate in bits per pixel (bpp) - as sascha points out. For example, an uncompressed image is usually 24 bit (8bit/channel * 3 channels (r,g,b)). Anything at this or higher bitrates is (most often) not compressed.

In general, lossless compression can be achieved at bitrates of about 12bpp (a 2:1 compression ratio). Normally you can aim at much lower bitrates (e.g., 1 bit per pixel, 24:1 compression ratio) and expect decent quality, but it'll depend on the images you're dealing with.